# How to record ssh session and email them periodically?

Tags: ssh

Is there anyway to record all remote SSH client's activity on a linux machine and email them on a periodic basis?

Comment: Perhaps `sudosh` is of use to use? If users want to become root, they can only do it with `sudosh`, which allows you to replay the session. Perhaps it can be adjusted for non-root activity.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://serverfault.com/questions/588685/remotely-executed-commands

Answer (score 3):

It depends a bit on your actual use case. If your users can't be trusted you should consider revoking their access privileges.

A basic trick is to look at the `.bash_history` but that's completely unreliable.

A classical tool is [`script`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/script) which can be used to make a transcript of an interactive session, every keystroke, each backspace and the output of commands.

Much more sound is proper auditing such as with `auditd` .

If you're only interest is privileged `sudo` sessions set `loginput` and `logoutput` investigate `sudoreplay`

Comment: This is the more correct answer. =)

Answer (score 1):

First you'll probably want all SSH sessions to have `PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'` so that every command is persisted to history. Then you'll probably want a cron job to tail the last `$X` of lines of bash history and pipe it to `mail`.

It's awful, and I'm a worse person for having typed all that. I will now go wash my keyboard out with soap.

<sub>This is not foolproof or in any way an audit tool. It can be subverted, tampered with, and modified in many ways. YMMV. IANAL.</sub>

Comment: Use the Force inherent in `auditd`, Luke!

Comment: @DeerHunter That's the light side of the force. I explained the dark side.

Comment: _STOP UPVOTING ME, PEOPLE, THIS IS AWFUL!_